# Systemd service start error

Tags: linux, services, systemd

I have a Beaglebone Black (BBB) running Angstrom Linux (v2012.12). Since none of my other Linux machines have systemd yet, and Angstrom does, I figured I'd get familiar with systemd before its shoved down my throat on Debian. I'm fairly clear on systemd usage/capabilities but for one error I get when trying to start lighttpd. I assume the format of the error message is typical for a systemd service error..

When I try to start the lighttpd service, I get the following:

```
root@beaglebone:/etc# systemctl start lighttpd.service
Job for lighttpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status lighttpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

If I run `systemctl status lighttpd.service`, I get the following

```
root@beaglebone:/etc# systemctl status lighttpd.service
lighttpd.service - Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements
      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled)
      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-02-16 07:23:30 PST; 3min 3s ago
     Process: 872 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd.conf (code=exited, status=255)
      CGroup: name=systemd:/system/lighttpd.service
```

Running `journalctl -xn` gets the following:

```
Feb 16 07:28:04 beaglebone systemd[1]: Starting Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements...
Feb 16 07:28:04 beaglebone systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Feb 16 07:28:04 beaglebone systemd[1]: Failed to start Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements.
Feb 16 07:28:05 beaglebone systemd[1]: Unit lighttpd.service entered failed state
```

All of the systemd documentation I've been able to find doesn't go into details about errors like this. I never had any trouble with the old-school way of starting daemons, and I've been playing with Linux since 1995. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have checked nothing else is using port 80 (which I assume lighttpd is configured to use). Check that bonescript still doesn't have the port bound, stop it with:

```
systemctl stop bonescript.service
systemctl stop bonescript.socket
```

Comment: ahh.. totally forgot about the bonescript service.. Once I stopped that, lighttpd started right up.... Thanks for reminding me...

Comment: @lvdave could you mark this answer as the accepted answer, since it helped you?